# A subharmonic function with a growth property

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Let $B=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:x^{2}+y^{2}<1\right\} $
be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{2}.$

Can we construct a subharmonic
function $f:B\rightarrow\left[-\infty,0\right]$ such that
$$
0<\int_{\widetilde{B}}\left(1-x^{2}-y^{2}\right)^{-2}dV<\infty,
$$
where $\widetilde{B}=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in B:-1<f\left(x,y\right)\right\} $? Here $dV$ is the standard Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I thought that in order to answer this we need to control (understand) the growth
on sublevel sets of a subharmonic function.

The question was already asked on mathstackexchange and received no answers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment on the key ' the growth on sublevel sets'. Could you elaborate on the approach you had in mind? The way I see it, the question hinges upon whether $\{ f > -1 \}$ can meet the boundary $\partial B$ along a cusp.

Comment: @Leo It was just my vague comment. The integrand is singular w.r.t. the distance function and the domain can be seen as a union of consecutive level sets of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes". Let $E$ be some Jordan region in the unit disk on which
$$\int_E(1-x^2-y^2)^{-2}dxdy<\infty,$$
and such that $E$ contains $[0,1)$, and the closure of $E$ is contained in the open unit disk, except the point $1$.  Let $\phi$ be a conformal map of $E$ onto the right half-plane, such that $\phi(1)=\infty$.

Let $u=\Re \phi$. Then $u$ is positive and harmonic n $E$, zero on $\partial E\backslash\{1\}$. Extend $u$ to the whole unit disk by setting is equal to $0$
outside $E$. Then take $f=u-2.$

As you see from this example, the weight $(1-|z|^2)^{-2}$ is not very relevant. You can replace it by anything you like.

Comment: @Eremenko Does the existence of such a conformal map $\phi$ follow from Riemann mapping theorem?

Comment: @Hana_a_student: yes, it does.

Comment: @Hana_a_stuent: unless you work a bit harder and find such a set E for which the map is an elementary function.